# $f(x)$ is continuous and $\int_a^{\infty}\lvert f(x) \rvert dx$ converges. Prove that $\int_a^{\infty} f(x) dx$ converges

Tags: calculus

If $f(x)$ is continuous and $\int_a^{\infty}\lvert f(x) \rvert dx$ converges, how do I prove that $\int_a^{\infty} f(x) dx$ converges?
I think I need to play with the properties of integrals and absolute value, but I don't see a way to prove the claim... I need a direction please

Comment: Just write down the specific $\epsilon$ condition you have to show ...

Answer (score 3):

Hint: show that, for every $\epsilon>0$, there exist $\delta>0$ such that
$$
\left| \int_M^N f(x)\, dx \right| < \epsilon
$$
for every $M>\delta$, $N>\delta$. This is the Cauchy criterion for the existence of
$$
\lim_{b \to +\infty} \int_a^b f(x) \, dx.
$$
Reference [here](http://ramanujan.math.trinity.edu/rdaileda/teach/m4342f10/improper_integrals.pdf).

Answer (score 0):

The continuity hypothesis seems somewhat  important to me in the OP, and does not seem directly used (but present in the  Cauchy argument by @Siminore). So my answer provides a counter-example, and roots on the integrability of continuous functions on bounded  intervals.

Indeed, let $a\le A$ be two real numbers. In the bounded interval $[a,A]$, let $S$ be a non-mesurable subset, and  take $i_S$ the indicator function of $S$, equal to $1$ for $x \in S$, and to $0$ in the complementary set. Define $g(x) = i_S(x)-\frac{1}{2}$. Then $|g(x)|$ is constant on $[a,A]$, hence Riemann-integrable, while the integral of $g(x)$ is not defined. So in this case, absolute integrability does not imply integrability.

Then, similarly to @Henry W., define  $f_+=\max(f,0)$ $f_−=-\min(f,0)$, and $f = f_+ - f_-$. Now, continuity reappears: both  $f_+ $ and  $f_-$ are continuous as well. And one can prove they are thus   [Riemann-integrable](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Continuous_Function_is_Riemann_Integrable) on the closed interval  $[a,A]$. So $\int_a^A f_+$ and $\int_a^A f_-$ are well-defined, monotone and bounded, thus convergent when $A\to \infty$, thus the improper $\int_a^\infty f$ has a limit.